# Unopened .mac box - any value?

Tags: mobileme, icloud

I found an unopened .mac box. It's still in its plastic wrap, so the subscription code has not been used. Is this of any value or should it simply be thrown away?

Answer (score 2):

Apple takes [applications for refunds](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4445) for MobileMe boxes. I don't know if they would give a refund for .Mac or not, but it's worth trying.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4445

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get a refund (you may need a receipt to do so), since it's an actual box, you might think about donating it to
[Shrine of Apple](http://shrineofapple.com/about/). New site set up looking to collect and preserve every Apple product they can find in an online museum of sorts.

Comment: Apple has stopped taking any new sign ups since June 2011 - selling it on eBay as a historical item or requesting a refund might be the only ways to make money on this today.